# Geometric series with matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

How do you prove the following statement:

If all eigenvalues of a matrix $F$ are real and less than $\frac{1}{\beta}$ in absolute value, then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta^nF^n=(I-\beta F)^{-1}$

If the matrix is diagonalizable, the proof is very easy. But what if it is not?

To give some context, the above formula is almost equivalent to the formula for the sum of geometric progression in R with first term 1 and ratio less than 1. It appears in the end of first chapter of this book and it is used without detailed proof.
[https://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-James-Douglas-Hamilton/dp/0691042896](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691042896)

Comment: The claim holds for any Banach algebra with unit $e.$ Namely if $\sigma(a)\subset \{|z|<1\}$ then $a^n\to 0$ and $(e-a)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n.$ The proof makes use of complex functions theory. In the matrix case it can be done by decomposing the matrix into upper triangular matrices corresponding to different eigenvalues.

Comment: A less general result is that all eigenvalues lie in the open unit disk **iff** there is a submultiplicative norm such that $\|A\| < 1$.